# How to stop loader after some time?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have created a website where I load an SVG image before the website loads.  It works perfectly but the problem is that the loader image is not stopping and if I remove `class="loader-bg"` then the website does not load properly. How can I solve this issue? Please help me.

```
<div class="loader-bg"></div>
```

```css
.loader-bg {
  background: #ffffff url(../images/loader.svg) no-repeat center center;
}
.loader-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10000;
}
```

Comment: Removing a class will not stop a website loading properly. It's hard to determine what your issue is without seeing a working example of it

Comment: Actually on simple .html it work perfectly but when I manage all file with codeigniter framework loader image showing continuously

Comment: Well then start with some basic debugging to figure out what is going wrong … Start by checking the browser console for errors, and verify whether that class actually gets removed by whatever script snippet you are using for that.

Answer (score 2):

There can be two ways:

First is that you wait for some response and then remove loader.

```
success: 
    $('.loader-bg').css('display', 'none');
```

Second is that you set some seconds like after 5 seconds it will be removed.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    $('.loader-bg').css('display', 'none');
}, 5000); // it will remove after 5 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Use different readyStates to remove loader class when page is loaded.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
    //Remove loader class from div
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking.

Comment: "problem is that the loader image is not stopping" ??

Comment: `if I remove class="loader-bg" then the website does not load properly...` they clearly already know how to remove a class. The issue is that the 'website isn't loading properly' but that's far too broad for anyone to be able to answer.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done is,

- Added a permanent element to the page which you want.

What you want is,

- A temporary element which disappears once the page has been loaded(if I understand correctly.)

I think best bet would be to remove that element entrirely from the page after a set amount of time, or a trigger(like document.load), or just overlap that element with some other element which hides it, or hide that element using opacity:0.01 with animation-duration: 1.5s (or whatever you like) so it fades away using JavaScipt.

I will help us better if you can give more input though.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hide the div after the page loading complete

**Css :**

```
.hide{
display:none
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('.loader-bg').addClass('hide');
```

or

```
$('.loader-bg').css('display','none');
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use jQuery's `document.onload` shortcut and then set the `display` of the loader to `none` with jQuery's [`.css()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_css.asp) function.

**Using `$(function() {...});`**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#loader").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
#loader {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  padding-left: 25vw;
  padding-right: 25vw;
  padding-top: 25vh;
  padding-bottom: 25vh;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">Loading</div>
The document has loaded
```

**Using `$(document).ready(function() {...});`**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#loader").css("display", "none");
});
```

```css
#loader {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 50vh;
  padding-left: 25vw;
  padding-right: 25vw;
  padding-top: 25vh;
  padding-bottom: 25vh;
  background-color: skyblue;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="loader">Loading</div>
The document has loaded
```